# Design Component validation in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have added a few design components to a lightning web component.
Is it possible to create validations on the values that are inserted?

For example, there is a design component that it's value should be numbers divided by commas, `0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1`and i want to check their sum is 1.

is it possible?

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.validate();
}

validate(){
    var i,sum = 0;

    for(i=0;i<this.weights.length;i++) {
        sum+= Number(this.weights[i]);
    }
    if(sum !== 1) {
        console.error('sum error');
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "error!",
            message: "sum error",
            variant: 'error',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

This is what i have so far. the problem is, i can see the Toast Message only when loading the page, but not in the Lightning App Builder.

Comment: where is weights being used in html? can you show html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `numbers` is the name of the property you are passing in design, then you can do below:

```
connectedCallback() {
    if (this.validate()) console.log("VALIDATED!")
    else console.log("NOT VALID!");
}
validate() {
    if (this.numbers.find(num => typeof num !== 'number')) {
        console.error('Please enter numbers');
        return false; // do not proceed further as they are not numbers array
    }
    let sum = this.numbers.reduce((total, num) => parseFloat((total + num).toFixed(3)), 0);
    if (sum !== 1) {
        console.error('Total is not 1 => ', sum);
        return false; // do not proceed further as sum is not 1
    }
    return true;
}
```

***Please do not use console.log in your code, this is only for your reference. Use toast message or any other business logic.***

Comment: Is there a way i can show it on the Lightning App Builder screen as a validation on the field itself?

Comment: @DanaGriff Can you please update the question with relevant code ?

Comment: code is updated